# Random walk on an interval and hitting times

Tags: real-analysis, probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a random walk starting at $x_0 \in [0,1]$. At any discrete time step $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the new position is given by: $$x_k = \min\{\max\{x_{k-1}+C_k,0\},1\}$$ where $C_k$ are continuous i.i.d. random variables with support in $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, we are moving at random in $[0,1]$ and we have a certain probability to be ''absorbed'' at $0$ or $1$ and then eventually reflected back.

I am trying to prove that the average minimum time needed to hit state $0$ for the first time (hitting time) starting from a generic state $x_0=y \in [0,1]$, call it $\mathbb{E}_y[\tau_0]$, is always smaller or equal to the same hitting time but starting from state $x_0=1$, call this $\mathbb{E}_1[\tau_0]$. In other words, I need to show that $$ \mathbb{E}_y[\tau_0] \le \mathbb{E}_1[\tau_0]$$
This seems obvious to me as the state $y$ will always be closer to state $0$ than state $1$, and hence it should take a shorter time to hit state $0$.

Any idea about how this could be formally proved?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if we have a sequence of random variables $X_k$ that starts with some $x_0\in[0,1]$, then we always have $X_k\le \tilde X_k$ where $\tilde X_k$ is the sequence that starts with $x_0=1$, so the same is true for the expected value of the hitting times and even for the hitting times themselves.

Comment: Mmh that's not necessarily true. I mean, it is true if the two sequences get the same increments $C_k$ at each time step but not if you sample those independently. What am I missing?

Comment: But if you choose "different" random variables $C_k$ and $\tilde C_k$ for $X_k$ and $\tilde X_k$, that doesn't change the distribution of the stopping times, so you might as well choose $C_k = \tilde C_k$ since you are only interested in the expected value, no?

Comment: I mean, "renaming" the elements of your event space $\Omega$ should do the trick if you look at "different" $C_k$ and $\tilde C_k$ (unless I am missing something silly, of course.)